# How to use new google voice searcher to write text in notepad?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, notepad, voice

I find out that google voice searcher is perfect tool to write instead of typing, but it works only at chrome and limited time. Now my question is how to configure windows to use those tools for writing long text in notepad?

Comment: check out Dragon Naturally Speaking, for speech to text. http://www.nuance.com/index.htm , it was the only speech to text that I have used that could come close to ending typing letters as we know it. Cons: there is a lot of odd things that a person types that are not in even the best dictionaries.  This was typed with a keyboard :-)

Comment: hehe ... i see there is no typical words mistakes which programs spech to text do :) ... thnx for comment i use before some time dragon but it don't have for my language (croatian) support, google voice have and is working great.